# Chrome WebDriver doesn't select from dropdown

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have got the following code working on Firefox, but not on Chrome.

```
Select selectSize = new Select(dropDownListBox);
selectSize.selectByIndex(1);
```

I've tried using explicit wait and Thread.sleep(), but couldn't make it work.

When I debug the code, I found out that it actually grabs the value, but doesn't update the UI.

When I use `System.out.println(selectSize.getFirstSelectedOption().getText());` it actually prints the size.

I've also tried running this code on iPhone and iPad emulators and it worked on there as well. I feel like this only doesn't work with Chrome Driver.

Has anyone had this issue before or do you have any suggestions?

Update: I'm using Selenium 2.41.0 and Chrome WebDriver 2.9.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any errors? What version of Selenium? What version of ChromeDriver?

Comment: @Arran Selenium 2.41.0, Chrome WebDriver 2.9, and it doesn't throw any errors. Driver thinks that is selecting.